# Dealing with Queue Manager in datapower

Tags: queue, ibm-datapower

I've requirement to check on the status of Queue manager in datapower first before sending any request to the queue in case if it's down it'll route to another queue 
is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by status? DataPower has Queue Manager Group that allows you to set Primary and Secondary Queue Managers. If Primary down, it automatically switch to secondary.

Comment: I mean the status of queue that I'll send the request to. I have MPGW service which receives xml as request and throw it on queue but before throw it I have to check on queue status before sending that request, in case the queue is down I have to route that xml to another queue

how can I achieve this using xslt